# Unable to use commands in VB6 Data Environment

Tags: database, vb6, command

I am working with vb6 project and I have a big problem. I use data environment for my project but I can not use commands. For example, in the button when I write `dataenvironment1.rsmycommand`, vb cannot find it, and when the program is run, this error is shown: "Method or data member not found".

This is part of my codes

```
 DE1.rscmdGetPersonalNumber.Close

 DE1.rscmdGetPersonalNumber.Open "Select * from Tbl_Members where PersonalNumber=1500 "
```

This is my SQL command

```
DE1.rsCMD_GetPersonalNumber.Open "insert into Tbl_Members(PersonalNumber,Name,Family,PasportCode,TelNumber,MemberType,WorkDate,StartWorkTime,EndWorkTime,Password,AdminGroup,Active) values(" & NewMember.PersonalNumber & ",'" & NewMember.Name & "','" & NewMember.Family & "','" & NewMember.Pasport & "','" & NewMember.Tel & "'," & NewMember.Type & ",'" & NewMember.WorkDates & "','" & NewMember.StartTime & "','" & NewMember.EndTime & "','" & NewMember.Password & "'," & NewMember.IsManage & "," & NewMember.IsActive & ")"
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this guide:

[Accessing databases using the DataEnvironment Controll](http://pages.cpsc.ucalgary.ca/~saul/vb_examples/tutorial4/)

follow this line:

> Go to the Project menu and select Components. In the Designers tab, select the checkbox for Data Environment and click OK.

Comment: Thank you Guy . I check your solution but this not working :(

Comment: So please tell me more about your problem.

Comment: OK . when you write code in vb , one list is open beside your typing location and suggest you some items . when I type "Dataenvironment." this list do not show to me rsmycommand and can not find it .

Comment: Does "Dataenvironment" exists ? VB recognize it?

Comment: DE1.rscmdGetPersonalNumber.Close
DE1.rscmdGetPersonalNumber.Open "Select * from Tbl_Members where PersonalNumber=1500 "

Comment: Hi, Please edit your original message and put the code there, I'm sorry but I can't understand it here.

Comment: Sorry, I can't find any problem. Maybe you should provide more code.

Comment: I have not many codes because I start this project Recently . yesterday everything is ok , but today when I wanted to work with project I confront to this problem . I test it on other pc and windows xp but does not work . I know my codes is correct but vb say not correct !

Comment: I said. Vb say " method or data member not found "

Comment: Thank you Guy . I can not find my problem but I delete DataEnvironment1 and create again . now work correctly . Thank you ;)

Comment: Sorry Guy . can you tel me about problem of this sql command ? (sorry I am beginner)